# Can't access css files in my public folder - laravel 6.2

Tags: php, laravel

I know this question has been asked many times but unfortunately i can't seem to get this working. I have my assets in **public/vendor/** and **public/css/** . When i upload files on my live server, it works perfectly. All assets in the public folders are accessed but not on localhost , i keep getting 404 errors (file not found)

**Login.blade.php**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('public/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('public/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css') ?>" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('public/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-select.min.css') ?>" type="text/css">
```

I have my index.php in my public folder

**index.php**

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: what is your local full url is it include `public` in url ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul, it doesn't include public in the url. http://localhost:8000/login

Comment: could you try <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fontastic.css">, notice /css

Comment: @AnuratChapanond, same error - 404

Comment: you may want to recheck config/filesystems.php in 'disks' => 'public' to make sure that it points to the right path.

Comment: @KamleshPaul, i have made some changes. That is how my login references look by like by default

Comment: @AnuratChapanond i have made some changes. That is how my login references look by like by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `public` from here `asset()` function directly target `public` dir

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css') ?>" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-select.min.css') ?>" type="text/css">
```

and as your using laravel don't use `<?php echo ?>` it is in `{{ }}` in laravel

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css') }}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-select.min.css') }}" type="text/css">
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset

Comment: Thanks but how come it works on the live server ?

Comment: you need to remove `public` from url it will work on live server as well